# Extract OpenCV Contour Array from Blob Detection in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, image-processing, contour

I'm playing around with blob detection techniques in C++ and OpenCV but I'm having trouble extracting the contour information in a usable format.

Currently I have all contour data stored as an array in a `cv::Point` format; however, I wish to extract the coordinates and store them in an array under a variable so I can manipulate this data as needed.

My code looks like this:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("frame-1.jpg");
    if (src.empty())
        return -1;

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(~src, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::threshold(gray, gray, 160, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    // Find all contours
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(gray.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    // Fill holes in each contour
    cv::drawContours(gray, contours, -1, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255), -1);

    cout << contours.size();

std::vector<cv::Point> minXY(contours.size()); // Top Left Point of Bounding Box
std::vector<cv::Point> maxXY(contours.size()); // Bottom Right Point of Bounding Box
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size()){
    minXY[i] = maxXY[i] = contours[i][0];  // Assumes the contour has at least 1 point
    for(int j = 1; j < contours[i].size(); ++j){
         if (contours[i][j].x < minXY[i].x){
            minXY[i].x = contours[i][j].x;
         } else if (contours[i][j].x > maxXY[i].x){
            maxXY[i].x = contours[i][j].x;
         }
         if (contours[i][j].y < minXY[i].y){
            minXY[i].y = contours[i][j].y;
         } else if (contours[i][j].y > maxXY[i].y){
            maxXY[i].y = contours[i][j].y;
         }
    }
}

    namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("MyWindow", gray);

    waitKey(0);

    destroyWindow("MyWindow");

    return 0;
}
```

The result of `contours[2]` gives an array with contour coordinates of the third blob; however, I want to extract this array into a normal variable so I can actually use it. I'm assuming this means some sort of `cv::Point` conversion?

UPDATE: I should probably clarify that I'd like the coordinates of largest blob's contour so that I can manipulate the data such as finding the smallest x point, finding the average x point, find the centroid of the blob etc.

Currently I have been able to find all the contours and then identify the largest blob, as well as identify its contour coordinates. However, I haven't found a way to search through this array to find the least x value, or a method to sum just the x coordinates. I would ultimately also like to find the most efficient method of finding the blob's centroid (using bounding box, moments, simple arithmetic or other method.)

** contours[2] spits out an array in the form:

> [100, 267] 
>   [101, 270] 
>   [102, 271]

I want to find a way to search the left column (ie. all the x values) to find the smallest and largest etc. I've tried several methods but none have gotten me close. Surely there's an easy solution to this. It seems all my problems stem from the fact that the contour array is in the form of cv::Point.

Comment: Is this what you want, `std::vector<cv::Point> xxx = contours[2]`?

Comment: What's wrong with using cv::Point?  You can access points coordinates as point.x and point.y

Comment: You should probably clarify your concept of "usable"

Comment: Yeah I was a bit vague with that - sorry I'm quite new to C++ and these forums. I basically want to take the contour array of a specific blob and find the average x value, average y value and maybe some other simple mathematical manipulations of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the points that make up the 3rd contour you can do the following:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> my_contour = contours[2];
```

or you can just loop over all of the countours by doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i){
   double avg_x(0), avg_y(0); // average of contour points
   for (int j = 0; j < contours[i].size(); ++j){
      // Do whatever you need to do with the points in the ith contour
      avg_x += contours[i][j].x;
      avg_y += contours[i][j].y;
   }
   avg_x /= contours[i].size();
   avg_y /= contours[i].size();
   cout << avg_x << " " << avg_y << endl;
}
```

From your comment you also wanted to calculate the centroid of the contour.

You can find the moments of each blob using OpenCV

```
std::vector<cv::Moment> moments(contours.size());
std::vector<cv::Point> centroids(contours.size());
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size()){
    moments[i] = cv::moments(contours[i], false);
    centroids[i] = cv::Point(moments[i].m10/moments[i].m00, moments[i].m01/moments[i].m00);
}
```

The 0th moment is the area of the blob, first moments the centroid and 2nd moments can be used to find orientation and eccentricity of the blob.

Wikipedia is a good starting place for learning more about image moments. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment

Using OpenCV you can get the Bounding Box and enclosing circle of a contour by first approximating it's contour as a polygon.

The following code is from [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html)

```
std::vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
std::vector<cv::Rect> boundingRect (contours.size());
std::vector<cv::Point> center(contours.size());
std::vector<float> radius(contours.size());
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i){
  cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true);
  boundingRect[i] = cv::boundingRect(cv::Mat(contours_poly[i]));
  cv::MinEnclosingCircle((cv::Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i]);
}
```

Or you can do it yourself (for bounding box).

```
std::vector<cv::Point> minXY(contours.size()); // Top Left Point of Bounding Box
std::vector<cv::Point> maxXY(contours.size()); // Bottom Right Point of Bounding Box
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size()){
    minXY[i] = maxXY[i] = contours[i][0];  // Assumes the contour has at least 1 point
    for(int j = 1; j < contours[i].size(); ++j){
         if (contours[i][j].x < minXY[i].x){
            minXY[i].x = contours[i][j].x;
         } else if (contours[i][j].x > maxXY[i].x){
            maxXY[i].x = contours[i][j].x;
         }
         if (contours[i][j].y < minXY[i].y){
            minXY[i].y = contours[i][j].y;
         } else if (contours[i][j].y > maxXY[i].y){
            maxXY[i].y = contours[i][j].y;
         }
    }
}
```

For contour[i]:

The most left point is at `MinXY[i].x`

the right most point is at `MaxXY[i].x`

the top most point is at `MinXY[i].y` (Note Y axis is inverted)

the bottom most point is at `MaxXY[i].y`

EDIT: To answer Modified Question.

```
float min_x = contours[2][0].x;
for (int i = 1; i < countours[2].size(); ++i){
    if (contours[2][i].x < min_x){
        min_x = contours[2][i].x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Please forgive my confusion - I'm very new to C++ / OpenCV. Basically I've identified the largest blob and also found it's contour coordinates, but I can't seem to separate the columns of the array to find the largest and smallest x values. I feel like there's something simple I'm missing here - maybe I'm approaching this problem from the wrong perspective.

Comment: Are you asking how to find the axis aligned bounding box of the blob/contour? AKA how to find the smallest/largest x and y values the blob occupies?

Comment: As in, trying to find the smallest x coordinate on the blob's contour (finding the left-most point of the blob) etc.

Comment: Those are basically the same thing. Except you just want the smallest X value. Check the above edit. I find the min and max value for x and y.

Comment: Using the bounding box code I get an error for the .x and .y portions that state "error class std::vector<cv ... etc ... has no member 'x'". Also - is there a way to just loop over one blob? Because I know the contour index of the largest blob so I really only need to search that array for the largest and smallest x & y values.

Comment: Yes. Instead of using the outer for loop (that uses i) just use the index you want instead of i inside the inner for loop.

Comment: @MSTTm Check the answer to the fix for the compiler error. (I forgot to index by j when I origionally wrote the bottom code).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in your last comment. I'm trying now to loop within the selected blob's array but I'm hitting a wall - because of the way the contour coordinates are stored as cv::Point I cannot compare the values contours[2][j] with another variable to find the least value. All I wish to do is extract the data out of this cv format and into just a normal variable where I can use operators like + and -, as well as storing parts of the array as other variables.

Comment: contours[2][j].x is the x value of the point and contours[2][j].y is the y value. (both of which are floats and can be used anywhere you can use any other float). You should use those to access the x and y points.